# jQuery error in IE8 - .val() or trim()?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm getting a jquery error in the IE8 debugger but I'm not sure which function is causing it. I've seen a whole bunch of posts here that state that IE8 doesn't support native trim(), but I'm not (I don't think) using a native version (I inherited this code; it's not something I wrote from scratch.)

Here's the chunk that's causing issues - it's part of a click function:

```
greenlight = false;
link = $(this);
href = $(this).attr("href");
row = $(this).parent().parent();
if ($(":text", row).exists()) {
    new_email = jQuery.trim($(":text", row).val());
        //do stuff here

}
```

The error I'm getting in the debugger is on the line starting new_email; the error is "Object doesn't support this property or method."

Can anyone help me figure out 1) which property or method IE8 doesn't support, and 2) what I can do to fix it? I'm in no way a jquery expert; I'm 99% server-side.

The code does work in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

Comment: It would make it much easier for us to help you if you could reproduce the problem at a publicly accessible page or on http://jsfiddle.net/. Also, line numbers in IE JavaScript errors are often misleading, try to run your code with the IE Developer Tools debugger and set a breakpoint.

Comment: I did run the code with the developer tools and set several breakpoints - one on the line immediately before the one referenced in the error and one on the line after it. It made it past the first one, and blew up before the second one. And I understand the need for code in general, but this is part of a huge Drupal site with bits and pieces of the code all over the place. There's no easy way to pull in anything that might be affecting things.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update:
Due to new information, I think you come accross an issue with IE where it will have a conflict when you have a variable and a element IDed with the same name it will cause conflicts and confusing error messages about functinality not exitsting. See this reference for a more detailed explanation. http://www.karlstanley.net/blog/?p=5

Original Answer:
If you are having problems debugging a single complex line split it into parts,

```
var tempValue = $(":text", row).val();
new_email = jQuery.trim(tempValue);
```

Comment: OK, I tried this, and used console.log to print out the value of tempValue. It displays what's expected. However, I'm still getting the error on the next line. And the funny thing is, it says the error is on character 4, which is the underscore. Could IE really be blowing up at an underscore in a variable name?

Comment: Apparently that is the case; I just changed the variable name from new_email to newEmail, and it works correctly. I'm slightly freaked out, since there are dozens of functions in this application that contain variables with underscores in the names.

Comment: Could it be you have run into the naming conflict between dom elements and javascript variables in IE? http://www.karlstanley.net/blog/?p=5

Comment: @Robert - YES!!! That's it! Thank you so much - I knew I wasn't crazy. As I said, I inherited this code and there are pieces I'm not as familiar with, and there is indeed a field, buried way down on a huge form, that's named new_email.

Comment: @Robert, if you want to post that comment as an answer, I can accept it so you get credit...

Comment: Great! Worked for me as well. Just for others, I had a select element with a name attribute of "year1". When I tried to set a variable called `year1` to the value of that select element, I got the error.  Changing `var year1 = $('select[name=year1]').val();` to `var first_year = $('select[name=year1]').val();` fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
$(":text", row).exists()
```

To:

```
$(":text", row).length > 0
```

There's no `exists()` function in the jQuery library as far as I know ([tried searching the API reference](http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=exists)).

Comment: I'll give it a shot, but why would it work on the other browsers if that's the case?

Comment: Hmm, my train of thought was that the object or array prototype had the `exists` function defined, and IE didn't implement it, which is totally wrong and not the case. The rest of the code looks fine, that was the only questionable part, I can't explain why it works in FF, because `typeof $(':text').exists` returns 'undefined'

Comment: Nope, I tried your change and still get the same error on the same line. So it's not the exists() that's causing the problem (or not only that.)

Comment: `exists()` is definitely not a method in jQuery. Even if that didn't fix the issue, keep the change!