# Code to hide elements of combo box works in chrome/mozzila, doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

```
$("inp:preAprovacao").children().each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "1. CTINF") {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

It's working on Chrome as supposed, but it simply does not work in Internet Explorer. I cannot figure out why.

EDIT: I replaced .hide() with .remove() and it worked. It's something to do with hiding the item in the combo box.

Comment: You didn't put all your code, but it might have something to do with the problem explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952666/jquery-error-in-ie8-val-or-trim). Apparently `.val()` doesn't evaluate correctly in IE if there's an element with the same ID as a variable.

Comment: these elements in the DOM have no ID

Comment: No idea, then. I can't wait until Internet Explorer no longer exists/is always up-to-date (as if!). They should implement a feature which forces you to update before you get to browse.

Comment: $("inp:preAprovacao") this looks very suspicious

Comment: I replaced .hide() with .remove() and it worked. It's something to do with hiding the item in the combo box. Any ideias?

Answer (score 0):

Maby this could help you?
 $(this).css('display','none');