# Radio button checked or not using jquery not working in ie8?

Tags: php, jquery, radio-button

I want to check which radio button selected and i use following script but it is not working. when i select <kbd>y</kbd> button nothing will happen but when we click another button the it give me value of <kbd>y</kbd> button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function filtersearch()
   {    
      var waitcharge = $("input:radio[name='waitcharge']:checked").val();
   }
</script>
```

here is my form that contain radio button

```
<form id="filterform">    
    <div class="sidebar_inner_options form-group" id="sidebarhome">
    <div class="col-sm-6 filterindent"><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="y" name="waitcharge" id="waitcharge" onchange="filtersearch();"/> Y</label></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 filterindent"><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="n" name="waitcharge" id="waitcharge" onchange="filtersearch();"/> N</label></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 filterindent"><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="na" name="waitcharge" id="waitcharge" onchange="filtersearch();"/> NA</label></div>       
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="filter" style="padding: 2px 11px 2px 11px;width: 65px;background-color:#F16E0E;border:1px solid #F16E0E;" id="filter"><strong>FILTER</strong></button>
</form>
```

Comment: What console errors are there in IE8?

Comment: oh. god.. id should be unique..!

Comment: This question has an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952666/jquery-error-in-ie8-val-or-trim

Comment: Your code works http://jsfiddle.net/x5E9w/

Comment: ID must be unique ,else jQuery doesnt funtion properly as expected.

Comment: OP has used duplicate IDs but not used with jQuery.

Comment: The event fires after mouse is clicked somewhere else after Radio box selection ,in IE8. OP is correct.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/x5E9w  code also not wornking in ie 8\

Comment: yes event fire after mouse is clicked somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to use [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) function here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var isChecked=false;
    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
        isChecked=$(this).val();
    });
});
```

Also each element should have unique id.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="filterform">    
        <div class="sidebar_inner_options form-group" id="sidebarhome">
        <div class="col-sm-6 filterindent"><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="y" name="waitcharge" class="waitchargeRadio" /> Y</label></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 filterindent"><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="n" name="waitcharge" class="waitchargeRadio"/> N</label></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 filterindent"><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="na" name="waitcharge" class="waitchargeRadio"/> NA</label></div>       
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="filter" style="padding: 2px 11px 2px 11px;width: 65px;background-color:#F16E0E;border:1px solid #F16E0E;" id="filter"><strong>FILTER</strong></button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    window.jQuery('.waitchargeRadio').on('change',function(){
        var waitcharge = window.jQuery(this).val();
    });
});
</script>
```